# How can i lint only one product flavor?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-lint

**Problem:**

When I execute gradle lint it lint both product flavors.
One is not ready, so it fails always (not all the strings are there).

**What i want:**

I really want some option to say lint only this product flavor

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can run:

```
gradle lintFlavorType
```

Also, in your build.gradle you can add this option

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify for someone else that stumbles on this, when Gabriele says lintFlavorType, Type refers to the build configuration (e.g. Debug vs. Release). So if you had a Pro flavor you might do:

    gradle lintProRelease